# insert Future Function into item count in list view builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, future

i have future function inside class :

```
class Todo{
Database? db;
Future getTheCount() async{
    var counte = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db!.rawQuery('Select Count (*) from $tableTodo'));
    print(counte);
    notifyListeners();
    return counte;
  }
}
```

and i have a listview builder:

```
ListView.builder (
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          itemCount: getTheCount(), //here is the error
          itemBuilder: (context,index) {
            return TaskTile(todoData.todo.title, todoData.todo.dateTime, todoData.todo.timeOfDay);
            },
          );
```

the item builder must be type 
and the getTheCount() Function type is

the error is: error: **The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int?'. **

how i can fix this error?

Comment: *"how i can fix this error?"* - as always when dealing with `Future`s: use `FutureBuilder`

Comment: use `FutureBuilder` to fetch the value from the function and then use it in the '`listview`. I would recommend you to use `FutureBuilder`. it is easy to use.

Comment: @pskink yeah XD